# Scale of Amplitude in FFT (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, fft, amplitude

Using Matlab's FFT function, I am getting different Amplitude values in a particular frequeny, when I use different range of Bandpass filters centering around that particular frequency. What's wrong here? How can a particular Amplitude scale be selected?

In the following code, I calculated two FFTs of the same signal over the frequency range of (59Hz to 61Hz) and (59.98Hz to 60.02Hz) after bandpassing them in the said range.

```
[x_noise,fs] = audioread(h);
x_noise = x_noise(1:length(x_noise)/360); 
xlen = length(x_noise);
x_main=x_noise;

i=1;
%%
%Noise
f1=59;
f2=61;
fn=fs/2;
w1=f1/fn; 
w2=f2/fn;

[b,a]=butter(5,[w1 w2],'bandpass');
xn_har = filter(b,a,x_noise);

%FFT of Noise
X_Noise = abs(fft(xn_har));
 p = linspace(0,1000,length(X_Noise));
 figure(1)
 plot(p,X_Noise)

%% 
%Signal
f1_sig=59.98; 
f2_sig=60.02;
w1_sig=f1_sig/fn;
w2_sig =f2_sig/fn;

[b,a]=butter(5,[w1_sig w2_sig],'bandpass');
x_sig_har = filter(b,a,x_main);

%FFT of Signal
X_sig = abs(fft(x_sig_har));
q = linspace(0,1000,length(X_sig));
figure(2)
plot(q,X_sig)
```

But after doing FFT, the Amplitude in 60Hz seems to vary a lot. As seen in the image, one has a value of around 1600, while the other has around 1.2. Why is this happening, they are at the same frequency?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be your filter. Designing a very narrow filter is very hard; a very large order is required and even then, some responses may simply be unrealizable. Note that "narrow" here is relative to the Nyquist frequency. I don't know what your sampling frequency is, but let's assume 8000 Hz. Run this code:

```
fn=4000;f1=59;f2=61;w1=f1/fn;w2=f2/fn;
b=butter(5,[w1 w2],'bandpass');
freqz(b);
```

The command `freqz` plots the actual frequency response of the filter that was returned by `butter`. It is very important *always* to verify that your filters' response resemble what you had in mind -- that is, that they meet your requirements.

I got slightly better results using `fir1` instead of `butter`. However, in your case, what I would try to do is to downsample the signal so that, relative to the Nyquist frequency, the filter is not too narrow. To see the effect, run this code:

```
fn=120;
f1=59;f2=61;w1=f1/fn;w2=f2/fn;
b=fir1(200,[w1 w2],'bandpass');
freqz(b)
```

You'll see a nice, narrow response with 0 dB gain at the center frequency and around -70 dB rejection out of band.

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but I cannot upvote yet(low rep). The Sampling frequency here is 1000Hz.  I still need to desing a Band Stop filter in range 59.98Hz to 60.02 Hz. But when I design it simply doesn't work. What should I do? Downsample the Data?

Comment: As I said earlier, what I would try first is to downsample, and then play with `fir1` until I got a filter that meets my requirements.